# How to set video params (text) to be shown inside video?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am ASPNET developer.
I want to place in my site some video templates so users can make simple editing like writing title on an object in side the video.

the user will enter his text into my DB and when ever he will play that video he will see the his text. 
I dont have any experience with video programming.

Even if I will not do that my self I will want to understand the process .

How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks Alot.

Comment: HTML5 video? Flash video? Have a look at jQuery and AJAX, you can do loads with those 2.

Comment: yes ,html5 and flash video.